# how can I exit from the app without clicking on exit

Tags: android

I have to exit from the app without clicking exit button.. I have 3 activities. One is main, another one is register and the other is login. I am in the login page so that if I press back  in the mobile , I should go directly to the home.. Help me friends !! Thankyou..

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to finish current activity when moving to another activity this will ensure that no activity runs currently except current.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
CurrentActivity.this.finish();
```

So now when you click back button it will not display the T&C page and will exit. But if you want to show any other page instead of exit then override `onBackPressed()` method.

Comment: it's working. But the problem is the activities are again appearing when I opens the app.

Comment: @user2637529: which activity exactly? can you please elaborate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

U want once u saved the details after that u want to open a new activity i hope .See this i have also done the same thing it will help u

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("shared", MODE_PRIVATE);
            if(shared.contains("username") && shared.contains("password")){
                startingActivity();
            } else {
                 //What u want to do here 
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem, as I understand, is that you are only calling `finish()` if the `SharedPreference` value is `false`. But you want to close this page no matter what or else it is still in the stack. So move `finish()` out of the `if` and close this `Activity` no matter what the value is.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean haveWeShownPreferences = prefs.getBoolean("HaveShownPrefs", false);
if (!haveWeShownPreferences) {
    Intent y=new Intent(this,Registerwithdialus.class);
    this.startActivity(y);

 }
 finish();
```

Let me know if I don't understand the problem.

Comment: If I do like this, app is itself not opening.. My problem is If I does not click the exit button and goes back from the app and if again I re enters to the app, the two activities should not appear as If it happens when I clicks the exit button. It shouldnot happen evenif I doesn't clicks the exit button.